# Кроссбраузерность CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, вёрстка, кроссбраузерность

У нас возник вопрос, касающийся именно css + html. При верстке сайтов, например, делаю 1 блок общий контент, в него вставляю 2 блока `left` (для меню и модулей) второй `right` основной контент, задаю обоим любые позиции `float: left;` или `right`, при этом они перестают тянуть вниз основной блок, в котором вставлены.

После того, как убираю данные позиции, они съезжают в центр и приходится их разгонять по сторонам параметром `margin-left margin-right`, всё бы ничего, жить можно, но именно в Google Chrome вылазит новая проблема: он не понимает параметра `margin` в стороны. Ни в минус, ни в плюс. При том что остальные браузеры - Opera, FireFox, IE - всё принимают прекрасно. IE даже на удивление косячит меньше, чем FireFox и Google Chrome вместе взятые. За Opera нет слов, принимает всё и никаких нареканий.

Но вот как можно справиться с данными проблемами, а именно - растяжкой вниз при указанных позициях `float: left;` или `right`, и с хромом, чтобы он понял, как-то `margin-left margin-right`.

**Добавлено.**

```
< !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
```

Comment: А какой у вас доктайп?

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div style="float: left"></div>
<div style="float: right"></div>
<div style="clear: both; height: 0; line-height: 0"></div>
</div>
```

У хрома возьмите стабильную версию: 10, например. Самые свежие всегда глючат, такой он. `*`troll`*`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! я догадывалась что хром убожество и вы это подтвердили:) Недоразумение а не браузер.

Comment: Отличных браузеров нет. Фаерфокс держится нормально и он объективно лучший, но и у него неприятных заездов куча(один plugin-container.exe чего стоит). Остальные просто помирают потихоньку.

Таки да, имхо, конечно.

Comment: Незнаю я например когда верстаю ничем не могу пожаловаться на ИЕ и Оперу вообще, а вот у хрома и фокса постоянно косяки, так же и Opera Hybrid отлично работает что по скорости что по всему. А как на мой взгляд фокс ещё тот тормоз. Мало того в отличии от оперы дырявый с кучей шелов. Тк фокс это народное творчество а опера всётаки официальная компания. На фокс пишут плагины кто угодно и как угодно. И кстати он с хромом косячит при верстке почти одними и теми же ошибками. Зато опера и ИЕ всё отлично принимают. Да ие может накосячить но он далеко не хуже в этом отношении чем фокс.

Comment: Меня ща закидают торвальдсами, но когда при работе в Delphi приходится верстать *только* под ИЕ - это приятно, легко и быстро с редкими вылазками на MSDN. Да, я знаю все его косяки, но если бы был только ИЕ - его бы закидали отчетами об ошибках и он бы работал лучше любых его нынешних аналогов. Так-то.
Опера для браузера непозволительно тяжелая. На хороших современных компах это незаметно, а вот где-нибудь в офисе ее лучше не ставить. Молчу про ее работу с флэшем)

Comment: Чесно незнаю о чем вы, попробуйте оперу гибрид, очень быстрая, с флешем вообще никаких проблем небыло. Но вот насчет тяжести она граздо легче фокса. Да за хром не спорю он легкий, но тупой. ИЕ воообще очень тяжелый и медленный. Если бы я расположила браузеры в хронологии от лучшего к худшему, вышло бы следующее: Opera, Web Kit, Fire Fox, IE, chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы ваш блок растягивался, достаточно указать overflow:hidden; height:1% - это нужно делать всегда для блоков которые содержат потоковые элементы (со свойством float). Но в вашем случае если вам нужны две колонки, то нужно сделать вот так:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:980px;margin:0 auto">
    <div id="sidebar" style="float: left;width:200px"></div>
    <div id="content" style="padding-left:200px"></div>
   </div>
```

именно так нужно делать две колонки для любых блоков.

Но для каркаса сайта я бы порекомендовал скачать лайаут хотя бы с csstemplater.com и посмотреть как он сделан. В идеале блок с контентом должен идти вверху, чтобы поисковики сначала индексировали контент сайта.

По поводу не любви к Chrome я с вами согласен, но был удивлен вторым местом Web Kit в вашем рейтинге, ведь хром основан именно на этом движке, который использует и Сафари, а в Сафари багов, глюков и прочего наверное больше чем в ИЕ.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> < !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
> ```

Во-первых, не надо использовать эту штуку. Во-вторых, а что там пробел делает.

Надо так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

> задаю обоим любые позиции `float: left;` или `right`, при этом они перестают тянуть вниз основной блок, в котором вставлены.

Google: `clearfix`.

Самый простой вариант - `overflow: hidden`. Самый распространённый - посложнее.

Итог:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.content { overflow: hidden; }
.left { float: left; width: 30%; }
.right { float: right; width: 70%; }
header, .left, .right, footer { border: 1px dotted; }
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<div class=content>
  <div class=left>Left Left Left</div>
  <div class=right>Right<br>Right<br>Right<br></div>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Теперь залить фон - один из вариантов - использовать градиентный фон родителя:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.content { overflow: hidden; }
.left { float: left; width: 30%; }
.right { float: right; width: 70%; }

header, footer { background: #FCD; }
.content { background: linear-gradient(to right, azure 0, azure 30%, antiquewhite 30%, antiquewhite 100%) }
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<div class=content>
  <div class=left>Left Left Left</div>
  <div class=right>Right<br>Right<br>Right<br></div>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

> но именно в Google Chrome вылазит новая проблема: он не понимает параметра margin в стороны.

Всё он понимает. Возможно, дело в <s>идиотском</s> доктайпе.